# Custom List Cell Renderer not showing icons in runnable jar file

Tags: java, swing, cell, jlist, renderer

I'm using Eclipse and I made custom cell render which is working while in Eclipse, but when I export project as Runabble jar file the list wont show icons of its elements, only text. What can be problem? Please help.

Comment: How do you load the icons? Are they contained int he JAR?

Comment: Solved, I'm sorry for false alarm, i forgot: getClass().getRecources()